# Refreshing browse why im getting HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

please help me why i'm getting HTTP `Error 404.0 - Not Found` after i refresh my browser

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute'])

    app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when("/Contact", {
            templateUrl: '/ApiClient/Contact/AdminContact.html',
            controller:'ContactCtrl'
        })  .otherwise('/', {
            templateUrl: "ApiClient/Home/Home.html"
        })
```

**Html**

```
<base href="/" />
<div class="col-lg-1">
        <a href="Contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your path is wrong, try it as

```
}).otherwise('/', {
    templateUrl: "/ApiClient/Home/Home.html"
})
```

Comment: check the refered path in the network tab and see if your file is there